# PHP/SQL - Combining AND & OR in a foreach()

Tags: php, sql, foreach

I'm sending json to the server like this:

```
{"data":{"tags":[{"tag":"Paris"},{"tag":"New York"},{"tag":"London"}]},"terms":{"term":"index"}}
```

... and with foreach() I'm appending the provided tags to the query:

```
$query = "SELECT name FROM accounts 
WHERE name = '".$term."'";
foreach($tags as $t=>$tag){
    $tag = $tag['tag'];
    $query.=" AND city = '".$tag."'";
}
```

... to replicate this:

```
SELECT name FROM accounts 
 WHERE name=$term 
 AND city=$tag
 AND city=$tag 
 AND city=$tag;
```

But how should the foreach() look like if I want to provide replicate this:

```
SELECT name FROM accounts 
 WHERE name=$term 
 AND (city=$tag OR city=$tag OR city=$tag);
```

Comment: use `IN` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better way to use [IN clause](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm) in query and [implode](http://php.net/implode) function to form it:

```
$tags_list = array();
foreach($tags as $t=>$tag){
    $tags_list[] = $tag['tag'];
}

$query = "SELECT name FROM accounts 
WHERE name = '".$term."'";
if ($tags_list) {
    $query .= " AND city IN ('".implode("', '", $tags_list)."')";
}
```

Comment: isn't it controversial that name = $term and name in?

Comment: @inxoy I think author of the question just was mistaken in the field name and it's not a reason for give me a minus. I've explained the base principle.

Comment: $tags_list = $tag['tag']; it wont work as you expected. It will result in last tag only.

Comment: @PhilippM what does your query look like after the formation? Make `echo $query;` and copy output here please.

Comment: Ok, now its working. I found my mistake ... I escaped the array: $tags_list = $mysqli->real_escape_string(array()); Thanks for the help on this. Hopefully I don't get too many downvotes for this question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The Problem with this is that in your sql query the column name couldn't have 2 tags at the same time. for example

```
WHERE name = true AND name = false
```

wouldn't make any sense.

so u should use something like this

```
WHERE name in ($tag, $term, $tag2);
```

and therefore u should adapt your php code as well

```
$first = true;
$query = "SELECT name FROM accounts 
WHERE name2 = '$term' and name in ("
foreach($tags as $t=>$tag){
    $tag = $tag['tag'];
    if($first == false) {
        $query.=",";
    }
    $query.="'".$tag."'";
    $first = false;
}
$query.=")";
```

Comment: I would remove the foreach, and replace it with array_column and implode.

Comment: I wanted to help him with his problem and therefore using his coding style. doe it would definitely make sense to use implode

Comment: There are actually two columns ... I edited it above. Sorry for that. Should I still use in() ?